# CodeIgniter AJAX file not uploading

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My form in view is

```
<?php 
      $attributes = array('id' => 'myForm');
      echo form_open_multipart('', $attributes); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Main Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">ADD</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

And my script is as follows

```
<script>

    $("#add").click(function () {

        var image = $("#image").val() ;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('form/addArticleData'); ?>",
            data: { 

                image: image,

            },
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    alert($.trim(data));
                    $("#myForm")[0].reset();
                } else {
                    alert("Some Error Occurred. Please Try Again!!!");
                }
            }, error: function() {
                alert("ERROR!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my addArticleData function inside the controller form contains

```
if(isset($_FILES["image"]["name"]))  
    { 
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "images",
            'allowed_types' => "*",
            'overwrite' => TRUE,
            'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
            'max_height' => "768",
            'max_width' => "1024"
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
        {
            $data = array(

                'image' => $this->input->post('image')

            );
            //print_r($data);
            if($this->modal->insert($data, 'admin')) {
                echo "DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "ERROR";
        }
    } else {
        echo "FILE NOT SET";
    }
```

The problem is that whenever I tried to execute this script it alerts FILE NOT SET. And if I print $_FILES using print_r($_FILES);exit; it alerts an empty array.

Further if I try commented print_r($data);exit; and remove all the lines preceding it then  it alerts the name of the image uploaded as C:\fakepath\image.png

I just can't understand why this is not working. Please HELP

Comment: is datatype and URL are ok ?? Check that alert or console.log is coming in function or not .... and if it is image coming from that JQuery than dataType cannot be HTML

Comment: To perform uploads with AJAX you need to use [`formData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: A file `<input>` value does not contain the file....just the name string.

Comment: Still the same alert FILE NOT SET, no error in console

Comment: what do you mean @charlietfl

Comment: Can you provide some code for the same @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 3):

`.val()` is only going to give you the filename not the actual file.
To upload the file you need to use a FormData object and add the file to it

```
$("#add").click(function () {

    var image = $("#image").prop('files')[0] ;
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', image);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('form/addArticleData'); ?>",
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data) {
                alert($.trim(data));
                $("#myForm")[0].reset();
            } else {
                alert("Some Error Occurred. Please Try Again!!!");
            }
        }, error: function() {
            alert("ERROR!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is right answer but still i would doubt on the "dataType: "html",". I think this should change

Comment: @Rush.2707 well the code shows that the response is text, which is fine for html.

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Actually I have several field and I am appending all as                          
            `var data = new FormData();
            data.append('id or name',value);
            data.append('id or name', value);
            data.append('id or name', value);
            data.append('id or name', value);
            data.append('id or name', value);
            data.append('image', image);
            data.append('id or name', value);`

Comment: Please HELP , I can't figure it out

Comment: So `print_r($_FILES);` still gives you an empty array? What does `print_r($_POST);` give you?